# Convert from character to Date

Tags: r, date

I am running into some date issues when working with Dates in R.

Here's my situation-

I have a data set based on dates and finally got the Date field converted from character to Date in R using the following code

```
o1$Date <- as.Date(o1$Date , "%m/%d/%y")
```

(My dataset is `o1` and `Date` is the name of my Date column)

My Date column has the following values

```
"1/1/2013"  "1/1/2014"  "1/10/2013" "1/10/2014" "1/11/2013" "1/11/2014"
```

However when I convert the Char to Date I get the following Dates

```
"2020-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2020-01-10" "2020-01-10" "2020-01-11"
```

Any suggestions on what the problem could be and how to work around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at `?strptime` to see the formatting options for times and dates.  You need to use `%Y` rather than `%y` which is for a 2 digit year.

Comment: +1 %y is just getting the first two digits of the four digit year. %Y should fix.